# different versions point to same data source (db) - best practices

Tags: .net, database-design, architecture, application-design

Just wondering what would be best practices if i have application to be used for different countries. Data source (db) is accessible through single web service. Not every country upgrade at once. so what i feel problem could be. when i change add new cols/tables i will have to update services and previous version might not be compatible with that. What is best practice or minimum effort to accommodate such changes.

Comment: Versioning the requests to your service can help.

Answer (score 0):

The answer really depends on your requirements, but if your data model in behind a web service it shouldn't be to difficult to manage this problem.

Let's assume that US and UK use two different version of a table (US v1.0 and UK 1.1), the web service returns specific data for US and other for UK, so the web service receives a parameter to query to return the correct data to US or UK.

Now, if you have this parameter you can use it to point the request for UK to the table, which has the new structure v1.1, but if the request is coming from the US, the web service will point to a view which is still complain with v1.1. So your web service will become backward compatible.

It's just an idea, but I think can be worth investigating. You can also hide all your table behind views.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it depends on the details.

If the changes are relatively minor, of if they're mostly a matter of adding new fields, then it might just work to update the database for the new version. The old version of the software might work with the new database schema.

But probably not. You might get away with creating views so that the old software can look at a view that "simulates" what the schema used to look like.

You could have a "hyper-data layer" in the software that reads the database and then forwards data packaged in one set of objects to the old version and a different set of objects to the new version.

But frankly, I think if the changes are extensive and I had the choice, I'd make two databases rather than play games with it.

Comment: having multiple databases for each version would be difficult to mange... as releases' new version is very frequent...

Comment: in my case, i dont remove existing cols or amend them in anyway... i only add new cols/tables which i need to do deal with in new versions... so what i was thinking is.. add new tables.. doesn't effect in any way to old version but new cols in existing table would affect.. so to deal with them in procedures, i m thinking to add optional params this way previous version not passing wont throw error and new will send data in them

Comment: Yes, we regularly run into the situation on our development server, we usually have many programmers accessing the same DB for development purposes. So if I add new columns to a table and update a sproc to use them, I make the new parameters all optional, so I don't break the app for other developers who aren't running my new code yet. As long as you're just adding and not deleting or restructuring, that can work fine. It's when you say, Oh, this field that used to be a column in table A, there now could be many of them so I need to break it out into a new table with a many-to-one ...

Comment: ... relationship ... that's what trying to use the same db with old and new code starts to get tricky at best.